# Save record having reference to another record in Grails Domain

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have 2 domain classes: A and B, defined as follow:

```
class A {
    String data    
    static hasMany = [bs: B]
}

class B {
    String data    
    static belongsTo = [a: A]
}
```

Now we have field **a_id** in table **B**.
The problem is that I had **a_id** already, how can I properly insert a new **B** record with **a_id** as foreign key?

Currently I did like this:

```
B b = new B(
    data: "data", 
    a: A.get(a_id)
)
b.save()
```

=> To be able to insert the B record, I have to do one more query which get the whole A object, such a wasting time & memory since **a_id** alone is already enough.

Thank you very much.

Comment: instead of get use load(). And don't worry about the memory here, its not gonna cost you a lot of memory and it will fetch the object from cache if its already present in first level cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to do that, sadly.

If you want to optimize, consider using B.executeUpdate or even raw SQL

```
Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
sql.executeUpdate("insert into....")
```